# Branding / skin for ASP.NET MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm planning to design simple website using ASP.NET MVC new technology.
Many concepts are changed there comparing to classic webforms so my question is
how to prepare website to be able to change its skin or apply different branding, preferably using for this purpose different dns request name?

App_themes is not possible to use?

Thanks in advance for any clues

Tom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And App_Themes was never any good anyway.  It's limited.  Just use stylesheets, to change the theme you can include a different stylesheet.  As long as your markup is good then you won't have a problem. (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689759/asp-net-themes-should-they-be-used))

Answer (score 4):

Another more flexible option is to create a different master page, which can have a completely different html/css structure. When your views load, you can change the master page on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Oxite](http://www.codeplex.com/oxite). This blog app also has got [skinning functionality](http://oxite.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Skinning).