# Using different themes for different customers

Tags: asp.net

What is the best practice to apply different themes to different customers with asp.net.

Comment: Might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689759/asp-net-themes-should-they-be-used since the three answers so far say to use ASP.NET themes

Answer (score 6):

Use the built-in support for [Themes and Skins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

What Justin said.

If what you're really asking is how to dynamically set the theme/skin on the request, then the answer would be to set the Theme property of the Page or MasterPage during PreInit.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, you can apply the Theme in page code-behind:

```
protected void Page_PreInit()
  {
    Page.Theme = "themeName";
  }
```

To avoid having to type this for every page, you can put it in a base page that is inherited by each page you want to use the Theme.

Then, you just have to have a way to figure out from the user's information (probably stored in the database, retrieved on login, and carried around in a Session variable) which theme to use.

Answer (score 0):

I save the preferred theme with the client's info in my DB and i have an HttpHandler that sets it.